# (remove-if f lst) function on scheme

Tags: scheme

`(remove-all x lst)` function that removed anything in lst that was
equal to `x`. For this problem, write the scheme function `(remove-if f lst` that returns the list with all elements for which `(f x)` is true removed.

I have the simple remove-all code as

```
(define (remove-all x ls)
  (if (null? ls)
      '()
      (if (eq? x (car ls))
          (remove-all x (cdr ls))
          (cons (car ls)
                (remove-all x (cdr ls))))))
```

But how do I modify it so it takes in a function and returns the list with those elements that return true removed?

Comment: It'd be nice if you read this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Just pass along the comparison predicate as a parameter and replace the hard-coded `eq?` with the predicate:

```
(define (remove-if pred ls)
  (if (null? ls)
      '()
      (if (pred (car ls))
          (remove-if pred (cdr ls))
          (cons (car ls)
                (remove-if pred (cdr ls))))))
```

Or even better, use [`filter-not`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._filter-not%29%29) in Racket :)

```
(filter-not even? '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
=> '(1 3 5)
```